# Angular-ui-router is deleted automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, yeoman

So, I do a basic project using yeoman. 
After I install it, I want to use Angular-ui-router, so I do `bower install ui-router`. I injected `<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>` in my index.html and do everything as explained in many tutorials. 
But the problem came when I do the `grunt serve`, the `<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>` which I was injected in index.html is being deleted automatically. I need that component. 
Can you guys help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: which yeoman plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using yeoman angular generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeoman angular generator use [wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) for injecting bower components automatically. So first of all you should not add them manually it will all deleted with grunt serve as **wiredep clean that block and inject registered bower components**.

So every bower components should be on your bower.json file but I assume you missing `ui-router` you can add it to your bower.json manually or you can add `--save` on your bower command to save it to bower.json automatically.

```
bower install ui-router --save
```

run this one to save it on bower.json and then run

```
grunt serve
```

it will work...

Comment: @Liverpool it is good. By the way if you start recently to use yeoman I suggest you to use angular gulp generator which is doing all injections automatically and structure is much better.

Comment: whoaa, thanks mate will try to do that. great advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Add --save Or --save-dev while installing bower components which will add your installed component to bower.json.

```
bower install ui-router --save
```

once you installed bower components by --save then grunt serve will add all your bower components from bower.json to index.html file. So you no need to add bower components manually to index.html